# photoswipe height bug on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, photoswipe

I've got a problem with the height size of the photoswipe (v3.0.5) on iOS (only on iOS, it works fine on Safari or Android). We upload pictures to the server and save it with a resize of 800px max   (f.e. 643x800 or 800x530, it depends of the original size). The thing is that when we try to visualize it on our phonegap app on iOS, some images make the height of the page became bigger than the screen and they image don't fit to the screen. I think this bug has nothing to see with the css, because it works perfect with some jpg images and works fine on other platforms. The problems start when we upload png images or high resolution jpg images (I'd checked that we are visualizing the resize one).

Did it happen to someone else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. If you had this css code to photoswipe.css it will work perfectly:

```css
.ps-document-overlay, .ps-carousel {

    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;

}

.ps-toolbar { 

    margin-top: -1px; 

}
```